# Issue while converting string to date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have following table with records:

```
create table tblte
(
    dat varchar(50)
);

insert into tblte(dat) values('Sep 07 2018');
insert into tblte(dat) values('Sep 04 2018');
insert into tblte(dat) values('Sep 10 2018');
```

I tested following query

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`dat`, '%MM %D %Y') FROM tblte
```

I got below results. They all show null. Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: `%MM` should be `%b`.

Comment: Why are you storing dates as varchar in the first place?

Comment: `%M` is for full month names, and the second `M` is matched literally. So that would be for `SeptemberM 07 2018`

Comment: Also `%D` should be `%d`, `%D` is for dates like `7th`

Comment: Maybe you should consult the list of format operators in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to store the as dates, because converting costs time and you have it to do all the time

> ```
> create table tblte
> (
>     dat varchar(50)
> );
>
> insert into tblte(dat) values('Sep 07 2018');
> insert into tblte(dat) values('Sep 04 2018');
> insert into tblte(dat) values('Sep 10 2018');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`dat`, '%b %d %Y') FROM tblte
> ```
>
> ```
> | STR_TO_DATE(`dat`, '%b %d %Y') |
> | :----------------------------- |
> | 2018-09-07                     |
> | 2018-09-04                     |
> | 2018-09-10                     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bec7e4fcdfe321ea5272a4f0c1e53e05)*